# Straight lines detection in contour with openCV

Tags: c++, opencv, contour, edge-detection

I've just started using openCV with c++ and I need to do some rectangle edge detection.

This is the image that I'm using for testing:
[image]

and this is the result I'm getting by using thresholding (`THRESH_BINARY`):[image]

Using this code I'd say it's about 90% right:

```
void find_contour(Mat src)
{
    int largest_area=0;
    int largest_contour_index=0;
    Rect bounding_rect;

    Mat thr;
    cvtColor( src, thr, COLOR_BGR2GRAY ); //Convert to gray
    threshold( thr, thr, 175 , 255, THRESH_BINARY ); //Threshold the gray

    imshow("Binary", thr);

    vector<vector<Point> > contours; // Vector for storing contours

    findContours( thr, contours, RETR_CCOMP, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE ); // Find the contours in the image

    for( size_t i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ ) // iterate through each contour.
    {
        double area = contourArea( contours[i] );  //  Find the area of contour

        if( area > largest_area )
        {
            largest_area = area;
            largest_contour_index = i;               //Store the index of largest contour
            bounding_rect = boundingRect( contours[i] ); // Find the bounding rectangle for biggest contour
        }
    }

    drawContours( src, contours, largest_contour_index, Scalar( 0, 255, 0 ), 2 ); // Draw the largest contour using previously stored index.

    imshow( "result", src );
}
```

I'd like to get rid off the 'errors' on the right side and then draw polylines along each edge and find their intersection (card corners) so I can do a perspective transform.

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

I'm open to any suggestions.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Do you need to extend your technique to support other images? Because there are obviously some backgrounds for which thresholding isn't going to work too well.

Comment: Generally the cards will be white and the background will be a table (light brown). I've tried various code snippets and thresholding got me the best results.

Comment: Fair enough. I've been working with colour models of late, and there are some simple ones which might have been useful here, but if thresholding is enough for your needs I won't bother talking about them.

Comment: I'm willing to learn if you could point me to some resources ;)

Comment: One problem at a time. Anyway, my first though was to use a Hough transform, as they're nice and simple and easy to use and understand. Is this of any use? http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html

Comment: I've got pretty decent results using Hough lines, but only when using a good contrast between the background and the card. What alternatives are for thresholding to improve the accuracy in sub-optimal conditions?

Comment: Well, without resorting to fancy (eg. tricky and probably unreliable) colour segmentation, you could just try running an edge detector (eg. `cv::Canny`) on the original image and using the output of that to try and find lines or rectangles from. Even against a white background, it should find the red inner border of the card OK. You might have issues finding the correct rectangle against a background with lots of long linear features, but again: one problem at a time.

Answer (score 1):

I would try as follows:

- approximately find the corners; this can be done for instance by looking for the farthest outline pixels in the eight main cardinal directions, giving an octagon (plus some logics to select the right four points);
- from the corners, you get an approximation of the sides;
- place an appropriate ROI around every edge (slanted rectangle) and straighten it up to make the edge close to horizontal;
- use a Hough transform in the ROIs, preferably on the vertical gradient alone. A little horizontal blur can help as well.

The goal of using these ROIs is to reduce the possibilities of false detections and to make the detection direction-sensitive.